# \newcommand and tikzcd

Tags: macros, tikz-cd

Somehow it is not possible to combine `tikzcd` and `newcommand`, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dotheobvious}[1]{#1}
\dotheobvious{\[\begin{tikzcd}X\ar[r] & Y\end{tikzcd}\]}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options 

l.7 ...{\[\begin{tikzcd}X\ar[r] & Y\end{tikzcd}\]}
```

The output looks like this, the Y is missing:

[image]

What's wrong here?

Comment: Can I understand what you want to achieve? Could you please to add a figure? Thanks.

Comment: I just want the code of a `tikzcd` diagram to be part of the input of a macro (of course, a less trivial one) defined via `\newcommand`, but somehow this fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\dotheobvious}[1]{#1}
\dotheobvious{\[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]X\ar[r] \& Y\end{tikzcd}\]}

\end{document}
```

`tikzcd`  is a `tikzmatrix` which by default uses an active character `&` and like all catcode change commands does not work in the argument of another command, however it has an option to use a command form instead of `&` it seems conventional to use `\&` for this.