# Declare correctly a new symbol

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, symbols, packages

If I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\twoheads}{\mathbin{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]{\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]&{\mkern-10mu}\end{tikzcd}}}
\begin{document}
$A\twoheads B$, $a {\scriptstyle \twoheads} v$, $l {\scriptscriptstyle \twoheads} g$
\end{document}
```

and I would to create a new symbol named `\twoheads` using `\mathbin`, or `\mathrel`, or other commands (`\mathclap`, etc.), why have I this error?

> Undefined control sequence. [$A\twoheads]

What have I forgotten and what are the optimal solutions?

**Follow-up or and edit**: Looking the link of the very good user @campa I have tried to use the answer of brillant user @David Carlisle [\newcommand and tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412154/newcommand-and-tikzcd)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\dotheobvious}[1]{#1}
\dotheobvious{\[\mathbin{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em,ampersand replacement=\&]{\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]&{\mkern-10mu}\end{tikzcd}}\]}

\begin{document}
$A\dotheobvious{B}$
\end{document}
```

**1.** I have not understood the reason to put `[1]{#1}`;

**2.** I have understood the reason of `ampersand replacement=\&;`

**3.** If I had put `\DeclareMathCommand` instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand` why I must to add the `\[...\]` considering that `tikz-cd`, in particular, work in text-mode and in math-mode?

**4.** At the end the last code not work.

**Addendum: 2021/07/13**: I have followed the suggestion of the @egreg but I have not found a correct solution. This is the MWE with the errors:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\squee}[1]{#1}
\squee{\mathbin{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em,ampersand replacement=\&]{\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]\&{\mkern-10mu}\end{tikzcd}}}

\begin{document}
$A\squee B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error is in `\pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options` being undefined. When a TikZ matrix (such as a `tikzcd` environment) is in the argument to another command you must use `ampersand replacement=\&` and `\&` in place of `&`. Adding `\[...\]` is of course wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how to answer after the bunch of edits, so I try to go step by step... in order to be concise I assume that all the following snippets start with the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
```

---

The original question

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\twoheads}{%
   \mathbin{%
      \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em]
      {\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]&{\mkern-10mu}
      \end{tikzcd}%
   }%
}
\begin{document}
$A\twoheads B$
\end{document}
```

fails for the reason explained in [\newcommand and tikzcd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412154/82917) : `tikzcd` changes catcodes, and that won't work if you put the code in a macro because catcodes are already frozen.

---

You then try David's code and write

```
\newcommand{\dotheobvious}[1]{#1}
\dotheobvious{\[\mathbin{\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em,ampersand replacement=\&]{\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]&{\mkern-10mu}\end{tikzcd}}\]}
\begin{document}
$A\dotheobvious{B}$
\end{document}
```

but I think you misunderstood his point: the macro `\dotheobvious` just uses its argument, but David's point was that using it and passing the `tikzcd` as macro argument freezes catcodes, thus leading to the error. However, he put the code *inside* the `document`, while you tried to do it in the preamble. Of course you get errors, because you are trying to typeset in the preamble.

The `$A\dotheobvious{B}$` is just the same as `$AB$`.

---

Your third code suffers from the same problem. You have eliminated the `\[` and `\]`, but you are still trying to typeset in the preamble, and that will lead to errors.

---

Long story short: you want

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\squee}{%
   \mathbin{%
      \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.2em,ampersand replacement=\&]
      {\mkern-10mu}\arrow[r,two heads,squiggly]\&{\mkern-10mu}
      \end{tikzcd}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}
Inline math $A\squee B$, or
\begin{align*}
A \squee B
\end{align*}
in display math.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great campa :-)...as I can see the problem is the placement of the curly brackets within the command \mathbin. Why do they have to be placed by carving and putting a % comment? Always thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, the `%` and the indenting of the code are not necessary here because we are in math mode anyway. I'm just used to write code like that for readability, and to protect line ends with comment signs.